# Is there a Unicode symbol for an equiangular Y?

Tags: unicode

Is there a Unicode symbol for an equiangular Y? See `\downY` as in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf#page=31)

[image]

Comment: [No](http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LUCR/Math/unimathsymbols.html)

Comment: Bah, thanks. (although the absence of evidence is not evidence of absence. :-) )

Comment: The most you can get, is 2144, or the semi-producs: 22CB or 22CC. You may want to look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode for alternative symbols.